# Is possible to customize the models package path in Django

Tags: django

The default folder structure of a project in Django is something like:

```
myproject/
    - myapp/
        - models.py
    - myproject/
        - settings.p
```

Would it be possible to change that structure?

I'd like to do something like:

```
myproject/
    - myapp/
        - infrastructure/
            - models.py
    - myproject/
        - settings.py
```

or

```
myproject/
    - myapp/
        - infrastructure/
            - models/
                - __init__.py
                - some_model.py
    - myproject/
        - settings.py
```

I know I can make a `models` package and split the models into different files. But I'm looking to change also the name/path of that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. In that case, your app will be `myapp.infrastructure` and it will need to be added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.

Having `models.py` file and `models/` folder is mostly same for python. In this case, you will need to import different models in the `__init__.py` file inside the `models/` folder.

The idea is that somehow your models and other codes should be imported somewhere in the project for django management command to see them (ex: for preparing database migrations - makemigrations command). So as long as makemigrations can see your model, you can place them anywhere. It is just a python's way, not directly related to django framework.

As for the name of basic things (models, views, apps, signals, admin and etc.) - I think the only one required to be in its name is `models`. As it is used directly by its name in ORM. Check this: [Django Applications Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/)

So, it is possible thanks to python's syntax, but it is not recommended by django. Django's design practices were created to make it easier for everyone to write a readable app where you can easily understand where things supposed to be and work easily without learning internal rules of the project that someone else designed. It is very important for project where there are many developers and new members can join any time after the project's start. So, unless you are well aware what you are doing, you are free to develop any custom design you want - after all, all you need is for python to be able to import your functions and classes in other parts of the project.

Comment: Thanks, this is just for learning purposes. I'm trying to learn some hexagonal architecture concepts and I'm trying to applying those concepts to a Django project.

Comment: Nice. As I suggested, it is always better to follow best practices and recommendations for structure and syntax - but python mostly keep them just as a recommendation, not a rule. And some of "don't do it" rules can be useful for complex tasks for advanced developers.

Answer (score 0):

It's my solution

```
from importlib import import_module

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.apps.config import MODELS_MODULE_NAME
from django.utils.module_loading import module_has_submodule


class FlexibleAppConfig(AppConfig):
    models_parent_path = None

    def import_models(self) -> None:
        # Dictionary of models for this app, primarily maintained in the
        # 'all_models' attribute of the Apps this AppConfig is attached to.
        self.models = self.apps.all_models[self.label]

        if self.models_parent_path:
            submodule = "%s.%s" % (self.models_parent_path, MODELS_MODULE_NAME)
        else:
            submodule = MODELS_MODULE_NAME

        if module_has_submodule(self.module, submodule):
            models_module_name = "%s.%s" % (self.name, submodule)
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)  # noqa
```

```
class ClientsConfig(FlexibleAppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "clients"
    models_parent_path = 'infra'
```